# Reasonml type with multiple arguments, Error exception Failure("nth")

Tags: reason, bucklescript

I have got Error while compiling the following code

```
type shape =
  | Circle int
  | Square int
  | Rectangle int int;

let myShape = Circle 10;

let area =
  switch myShape {
  | Circle r => float_of_int (r * r) *. 3.14
  | Square w => float_of_int (w * w)
  | Rectangle w h => float_of_int (w * h)
  };

Js.log area;
```

> Fatal error: exception Failure("nth")
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand
>   failed.

When I change the `Rectangle` to tuple (int, int), it works

```
type shape =
  | Circle int
  | Square int
  | Rectangle (int, int);

let myShape = Circle 10;

let area =
  switch myShape {
  | Circle r => float_of_int (r * r) *. 3.14
  | Square w => float_of_int (w * w)
  | Rectangle (w, h) => float_of_int (w * h)
  };

Js.log area;
```

Is it not possible to have multiple arguments on a data constructor?

thanks

Issue has been submitted to buckelscript https://github.com/BuckleScript/bucklescript/issues/1822

Comment: That exception looks like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both variants are perfectly valid Reason code. You can have constructors with multiple arguments, and you're doing it right. Apparently, the problem is in the `Js.log` function, that is sort of a magic function and with the n-ary constructors,the magic fails.

So, my suggestion is (i) to submit an issue in the bucklescript bug tracker and (ii) do not use the magic `Js.log` function, but rather derive or write your own printer function and use it.

Comment: One of the many pains of using a newer language -- definitely submit a bug report to Reason so the developers know about it. Also in the mean time, [ppx_deriving.show](https://github.com/whitequark/ppx_deriving) might be useful? Not sure if this plugin would accomplish exactly what OP wants or even necessarily _work_ with Reason, but worth a look